# Mediation even though index of moderated mediation is not significant?

Tags: interaction, spss, mediation

I ran Hayes process macro in spss. In my results below, you'll see that indirect effects are significant on both levels of my Independent Varaible (IVAlgo), however the index of moderated mediation is not significant. Can I interpret this as the two mediators (Difficul and Trust5) mediates X on Y on all levels of W? It is my understanding that the index of moderated mediation just tests whether the mediation depends on levels of W. However, even though the index is not significant here, my results still provide evidence that there is mediation.

INDIRECT EFFECT:
IVUncert    ->    Difficul    ->    Trust5      ->    WOA_ceil

```
 IVAlgo     Effect     BootSE   BootLLCI   BootULCI 
  .0000      .0076      .0059      .0506      .0181 
 1.0000      .0080      .0065      .0400      .0206
```

Index of moderated mediation (difference between conditional indirect effects):

```
         Index     BootSE   BootLLCI   BootULCI
IVAlgo   .0005    .0073     -.0100     .0139
```

Comment: I have a similiar problem. But in my case only one direction is significant:
y model includes multi categorical independent Variable (x1, x2), two mediators, and one moderator. My output says:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXxQ5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXxQ5.png)
How can I interpret it? Please help meee :-))

Answer (score 0):

Yes you found evidence that the mediation (indirect) effect exists, but you did not find evidence that this effect is moderated by **W**.